# NDEF File works only on some apps (URL)

Tags: android, ios, nfc, ndef, lib-nfc

I am trying to emulate an url tag using libnfc and a PN532 module.

The ndef file works on "GoToTags" for IOS but it doesn't on "NFC Tools" or "NFC".

If I try to background-read it in android, it will say that there's not an available app for it even if any URL tag can be opened with Chrome.

For android I am using a Redmi 9C NFC

Is there anything wrong in this definition? Could it be other thing affecting the reading?

Here's the NDEF file I am using at the moment. I commented what I think every byte means but please correct it if there's anything wrong.

```
uint8_t ndef_file[0xfffe] = {
     0x00, //(Start Position) -> 0
     32, //(End Position) -> 32 Positions after this one.
     0xd1, //HEADER
     0x02, //Payload Count
     0x1b, //SIZE FROM 0x91 to END
     0x53, 0x70,//SP
     0x91, //UKNOWN
     0x01, //UKNOWN
     0x08, //Title Size (FROM 0x65 to 0x51)
     0x54, //T
     0x02, //2 bytes UTF-8
     0x65, 0x6e, // Language (EN)
     0x74, 0x63, 0x6b, 0x6e, 0x66, 0x63, //RcpNFC
     0x01, //TNF Record Type 0x01 "NFC Forum Well-Known Type" 
     0x0b, //PAYLOAD SIZE FROM "URI IDENTIFIER" to END
     0x55, //URI Records (0x55/'U')
     0x04, // URI IDENTIFIER 0x03 http:// 0x04 https://
     0x67, 0x6f, 0x6f, 0x67, 0x6c, 0x65, 0x2e, 0x63, 0x6f, 0x6d //PAYLOAD (google.com)
};
```

Thank you in advance.

Edit 1:
This is the code I am using to emulate the tag, even for the default code it won't work:
https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc/blob/master/utils/nfc-emulate-forum-tag4.c

I debugged the android device and this message appears:
`NativeNfcTag: Check NDEF Failed - status = 3`

Here's the relevant part of the log:
https://pastebin.com/zy884AMq

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc)

> To do this, the system reads the first NdefRecord inside the NdefMessage to determine how to interpret the entire NDEF message

And if you look at the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Nfc/+/refs/heads/master/src/com/android/nfc/NfcDispatcher.java#198)

`ndefUri = message.getRecords()[0].toUri();`

It only looks at NDEF record 0

and as it looks like (I've not fully matched that method of describing NDEF data) that your first record (Record 0) in a `Text` Record for which there is usually no default App installed (and it definitely won't be a web browser)

A `Text` record by default usually on Android causes the System NFC App to just popup a dialog box displaying the text in the `Text` Record.

This is probably different behaviour than iOS which probably ignores any records that are not `URI's`